# R curl fetch connection problem: time out reached

Tags: r, curl, connection, timeout

I've got some problem with the network connection of R.

```
library(curl)
req <- curl_fetch_memory("https://eu.httpbin.org/get?foo=123")
Error in curl_fetch_memory("https://eu.httpbin.org/get?foo=123") : 
  Timeout was reached: [eu.httpbin.org] Operation timed out after 10002 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I've got no problem when directly access the URL above in Microsoft edge.

```
httr::GET("http://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg", config = httr::config(connecttimeout = 60))
```

And when I specifically set the timeout to be 60 seconds as above, the code ran forever and I had to manually call it back.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] curl_4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3   
> curl_version()
$version
[1] "7.64.1"

$ssl_version
[1] "(OpenSSL/1.1.1a) Schannel"

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.11"

$libssh_version
[1] "libssh2/1.8.2"

$libidn_version
[1] NA

$host
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$protocols
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher"
 [6] "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"  
[11] "ldaps"  "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtsp"   "scp"   
[16] "sftp"   "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"  

$ipv6
[1] TRUE

$http2
[1] FALSE

$idn
[1] TRUE
```

I've already manually set my DNS to 8.8.8.8.
I'm in mainland China and I use VPN to bypass the GFW.

Comment: Hm, this might be a firewall/VPN thing: both work perfectly within a second on my machine as written :/

Comment: Thank you very much. ^_^ Any more suggestions?

Comment: You could try traceroute tools from the command line (`tracert` on windows, `traceroute` on most others). I suspect that'll provide the same error and tell you where the problem is, but beyond that I'm not sure. If you do get the same error, you could ask an additional question leaving the R part behind.

Comment: Still doesn't work after turning down the firewall.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can't tracert either of the said URL or google.com. But mainland URL like baidu.com and weibo.com works.

Comment: Yeah, probably a VPN or firewall something then. But I don't know enough about internet things to help debug much beyond that, sorry.

Comment: It's okay buddy. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem with reference to this [article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy) and by adding `:(mylocalhostaddress)` to the end of the proxy. Hope it helps somebody in the future. Thank you, guys.